# How do i write again to a file after reading it (or make a loop for the read and write process )?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a program that allows you to write to a file and then review it. My program only works if I add the text first then review. On the other hand, when I read the file and then try write to it again

I will have this error on this line `file.write(addtext + "\n")`:

`io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Here is my code:

```
file = open("notebook.txt","r")
file = open("notebook.txt","w")
while True:
    print("(1) Read the notebook \n(2) Add note \n(3) Empty the notebook \n(4) Quit")
    selection = int(input("Please select one:"))
    if selection == 1:
        file = open("notebook.txt","r")
        content = file.read()
        print(content)
    elif selection == 2:
        addtext = input("Write a new note:")
        file.write(addtext + "\n")
```

I have tried to add file.close after the reading process or replace this line of code `file = open("notebook.txt","r")` but none of them work.

Comment: Edit your question and format your code so that it looks more cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that **notebook.txt** exist. Else create that before using this code (or modify this code to manage case where this file doesn't exist).

You cannot write and read a file at the same first. First you read and after you write, use [with](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) paradigme to close your file automatically after usage and advoid **Too many open files** operating system error (if you forget to close your file after `IOError` for example)

Do:

```
_file = "notebook.txt"
while True:
    print("(1) Read the notebook) \n"
          "(2) Add note \n"
          "(3) Empty the notebook \n"
          "(4) Quit")
    selection = int(input("Please select one:"))
    if selection == 1:
        with open(_file, "r") as filename:
            content = filename.read()
            print(content)
    elif selection == 2:
        with open(_file, "a") as filename:
            note = input("Your note:")
            filename.write(note)
    elif selection == 3:
        with open(_file, "w") as filename:
            filename.write('')
    elif selection == 4:
        break
```

> Don't use `file` as variable name because it is a built-in function, in Python 2 see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) (same thing for keyword [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/keyword.html))

Comment: Thank you.Your solution works for me. But i can still make it work without the code `with`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your asking but I took a gander at your code and I tried my best to see what I could do.

So first I imported the **os** module in order to check whether or not the txt file existed on startup. If it did, then I opened it for reading. If not, then open it for writing.

As for the **while** loop, the first **if** statement opens the txt file for reading and then the lines from the file are stored in **content** by the **readlines()** function. And then I used a **for** loop to print each line in **content**.

The second **if** statement opens the file for appending and I used the **writelines()** function to write the user's input.

Here is my code added onto yours:

```
import os

if os.path.isfile("notebook.txt"):
    f = open("notebook.txt", "r+")
    f.close()
else:
    f = open("notebook.txt", "w")
    f.close()

while True:
    print("(1) Read the notebook \n(2) Add note \n(3) Empty the notebook \n(4) Quit")
    selection = int(input("Please select one:"))
    if selection == 1:
        f = open("notebook.txt", "r+")
        content = f.readlines()
        for line in content:
            print(line)
        f.close()
    elif selection == 2:
        addtext = input("Write a new note:")
        f = open("notebook.txt", "a")
        f.writelines(addtext + "\n")
        f.close()
    elif selection == 3:
        f = open("notebook.txt", "w")
        with f as filename:
            filename.write("")
        print("Notebook emptied.")
    elif selection == 4:
        break
```

*Let me know if this works for you and if you have any questions.*

Comment: Thank you man. Adding  f = open("notebook.txt", "a") make my program works. Also thank for showing me how to delete the text.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace

```
file = open("notebook.txt", "r")
```

with

```
 file = open("notebook.txt", "rw")
```

You might have to close the file prior to reopening it.

Comment: I have rewritten your code. This works fine                                                                                          #/bin/python3
file = open("notebook.txt", "w")
while True:
 print("(1) Read the notebook \n(2) Add note \n(3) Empty the notebook \n(4) Quit")
 selection = int(input("Please choose"))
 if selection == 1:
  file = open("notebook.txt", "r")
  content = file.read()
  print(content)
 elif selection == 2:
  addtext = input("Write a new note: ")
  file.write(addtext)
  file.close()

Comment: Exception ValueError: must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode